# OSX Mavericks: AppStore wring out my credit card number, but I haven't got any

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

My **problem** is that I can't even update my system or download a free app from AppStore, because it demand my payment information. There isn't any `None` payment info statement, so looks like it's obligatory.

**Question:** *How can I skip entering that info?*

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a support document describing this: [How to create an Apple ID without credit card](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534).